# Solution to 2nd order ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So my problem starts with applying the Laplace transform to a PDE.
After apply the Laplace Transform, my PDE becomes a 2nd order ODE:
$$\ddot{x}+\frac{2}{t}\dot{x}-\frac{p}{k}x = -\frac{A}{k}$$
where p,A and k are positive constants.
This does not look like a 2nd order ODE with constant coefficients so wondering what type of ODE this is and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your ODE is of the type in $y(x)$
$$xy''+2y'-axy=-cx \implies xy''+2y'-x(ay+c)=0~~~~(1)$$
Let $ay-c=z$, then we get a homogenous 2nd order ODE:
$$\frac{x}{a}z''+\frac{2}{a}z'-xz=0 \implies z''+\frac{2}{x}z'-2az=0~~~~(2)$$
Next Let $z(x)= u(x)/x$, we get
$$u''(x)-2au(x)=0 \implies u(x)=C_1 e^{x\sqrt{2a}}+C_2 e^{-x\sqrt{2a}}$$
$$\implies z(x)=\frac{1}{x}[C_1 e^{x\sqrt{2a}}+C_2 e^{-x\sqrt{2a}}]$$
Finally
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{ax}[C_1 e^{x\sqrt{2a}}+C_2 e^{-x\sqrt{2a}}]+\frac{c}{a}$$